# ListView OnItemClickListener error in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to add an item click listener on a ListView inside a fragment but getting errors,I'm using intellij idea.

Here is my source code:

```
 public static class FragmentFind extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        List<CinemaListItem> list=new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new CinemaListItem("Name",0,"place",200));

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find,container,false);

        ListView listView=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.cinema_list);
        listView.setAdapter(new CinemaListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.cinema_list_item,list));

       listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view1, position, id) -> {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ListView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

And these are the errors I'm getting.

```
 Information:Using javac 1.8.0_40 to compile java sources
    Information:8/30/2015 6:04 PM - Compilation completed with 30 errors and 0 warnings in 16s 595ms
    Error:Android Dex: [App] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    Error:Android Dex: [App] com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: 

    InvokeDynamic not supported
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.determineOffsets(ConstantPoolParser.java:226)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:132)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
    Error:Android Dex: [App] ...while preparsing cst 0015 at offset 0000005e
    Error:Android Dex: [App] ...while parsing C:/Users/ACER 15/Desktop/Android Projects/CinemaProject/App/out/production/App/com/example/app/FragmentPageAdapter$FragmentFind.class
    Error:Android Dex: [App] 1 error; aborting
```

I actually get no errors at first but i only get them when I add the **setOnItemClickLister**.

Thanks.

**Edited**
Here is the adapter class:

```
public class CinemaListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CinemaListItem>{

private List<CinemaListItem> list;

public CinemaListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<CinemaListItem> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    list=objects;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View view =convertView;
    if(view==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cinema_list_item,parent,false);
    }

    TextView name=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView distance=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance);

    name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    name.setTypeface(MyActivity.dekar);
    int dist=list.get(position).getDistance();
    distance.setText("" + dist + "m");

    return view;
 }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your adapter class?

Comment: I've added the adapter class.

Comment: You may try `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android (unfortunately) doesn't support lambda expressions. You can either use an anonymous inner class like below, or look into using a 3rd party library like [RetroLambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) which provides a backport.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
new OnItemClickListener(adapterView, view1, position, id) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "ListView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            });
```

Comment: Thanks.I have replaced the lambda with an anonymous inner class and i lost all the errors but i cant get the toast.

Comment: try after removing getApplicationContext()

Comment: I removed it but still having the same issue.

Comment: try to print Log.e("hello","ok");

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer after some researching.
The first error was of course from the use of **lambda expression** which i replaced with an anonymous inner class.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ListView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       });
```

And the lack of response from the List Items was solved by adding this line of code to the custom view of the list item (which in my case is layout/cinema_list_item.xml)

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

which is added to the parent layout

Comment: Thanks friend!, this is the solution to the onitemclicklistener in custom listview

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view1, position, id) -> {
 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ListView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
});
```